# Tabs within tabs not working properly using bootstrap 3

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am working on a webpage, where I plan to have to two menu tabs for one of the tabs on the Main-menu tab. I am able to get the Sub-menu tabs to show up on the page. The content gets populated properly for all the tabs. But, I am not able to navigate between the tabs. I am posting the code below of how I declared the tabs:

Header.php

```
                <div class="row clearfix">
                        <div class="col-md-12 column">
                                <div class="tabbable boxed parentTabs" id="mainmenutab">
                                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

                                                <?php include "mainmenu_links.php"; ?>

                                                <li class="dropdown" onclick="dropdownuserlogin()">
                                                        <?php include "userlogin.php"; ?>
                                                </li>
                                        </ul>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
function dropdownuserlogin(e){
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
$('#userlogin').dropdown('toggle');
}   


$("ul.nav-tabs a").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();  
$(this).tab('show').addClass('active');
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

mainmenu_links.php:

```
    <?php
$main = $_GET['main']; $sub = $_GET['sub']; /*echo $main; echo $sub;*/

$main_menu=array("Home"=>"files/home_page.php?main=1&sub=1",
                "Submit a New Project"=>"files/form_page.php?main=2&sub=2",
                "All Projects"=>"myday/.view_table.php?main=3&sub=1",
                "Innovations"=>"files/ideafactory.php?main=4&sub=4",
                "Share your learning"=>"files/shareyourlearning.php?main=5&sub=5",
                "Meet the Team"=>"files/team.php?main=6&sub=6");

$i = 1;
foreach($main_menu as $key => $value){
        if($i == "1"){
                echo "<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"../".$value."\"";
                if($main == "1" | $main==null){
                         echo " class=\"selected\"";
                }
                echo ">".$key."</a></li>";
        }
        else{
                echo "<li><a href=\"../".$value."\"";
                if($main == $i){
                         echo " class=\"selected\"";
                }
                echo ">".$key."</a></li>";
                $i++;
        }
}

?>
```

projects_menulinks.php

```
<?php
$main = $_GET['main']; $sub = $_GET['sub'];
$sub_menu=array("Myday"=>"myday/.view_table.php?main=3&sub=1",
                "Techpulse"=>"techpulse/.view_table.php?main=3&sub=2",
                "BrownBag Sessions"=>"brownbag/.view_table.php?main=3&sub=3");

$i = 1;
                        foreach($sub_menu as $key => $value){
                                if($sub == "1"){
                                        echo "<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"../".$value."\"";
                                        echo ">".$key."</a></li>";
                                }
                                else{
                                        echo "<li><a href=\"../".$value."\"";
                                        echo ">".$key."</a></li>";
                                }
                        }
?>
```

I think I am messing up something with the tabs declaration. Can someone please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You have missing to add bootstrap.js

Comment: @BaptisteDonaux - i have added the bootstrap.js at the end of the header file.

Comment: I think that in your header.php, at end file, you have a <script> tag too.

Comment: @BaptisteDonaux - I made that change..but doesnt work.

Comment: Look the doc.

$('#myTab a').on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
});

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage

Comment: I am using the same to declare my tabs. This is what I use for the mainmenu links - `$('#mainmenutabs a').click(function (e){
  e.preventDefault();  
    $(this).tab('show');
});`  This is what I use for projects_menulinks - `$("#allprojectstabs b").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();  
    $(this).tab('show').addClass('active');
});`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48002/discussion-between-rond-and-baptiste-donaux)